# View all jobs by company name

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

So I see that in the new Jobs tab when I search for a job and click on the link `View all X company listing` it is either redirected to the search job page where the result isn't refreshed without the button click or to the company job listing page under the tab `search company`. Why do you have two different redirections? Why can't it just be one method of displaying.

I think the redirection to the search job page is more appealing but better if the results are displayed without an extra overhead of clicking the search button.

Comment: Bug added to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report, this has now been fixed and pushed to prod.